# Segue from two separate view controller to same detail view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

This is my first iPhone app and my first exposure to objective c and Xcode.  I honestly don't know how to ask this in a single line(title) so I apologize.  I have a tab view application with one tab being a table view with a list of items and the other tab being a map view with pins.  The pins are for the same items in the table view.  When one of the cells in the table view is selected a segue to a detail view with labels, images, etc.  Depending on which cell is selected determines what info gets passed to the detail view.  I want the map pins to work in the same way...when a pins disclosure button is selected then segue to the detail view and pass the appropriate info to that view.

I don't know how to incorporate the same methods and functionality in the table view controller for my map view controller.  Should I just make a whole new detail view controller for the map view?  i then of course would have 2 detail view controllers with the same layout.  What is the most appropriate way of doing this?  I have a feeling someone is going to say to use the table view's methods and properties as a delegate, but I don't know where to start to go about this.  Looking for some direction.

ListTableViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ListTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *Parks;

@end
```

ListTableViewController.m

```
    #import "ListTableViewController.h"
    #import "TableCell.h"
    #import "ListDetailViewController.h"

    @interface ListTableViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation ListTableViewController

    - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
    {
        self = [super initWithStyle:style];
        if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar     for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    //Parks declared in ListTableViewController.h
    _Parks = @[@"BOMBAY", @"BOONE'S CAVE", @"EAST DAVIDSON", @"HAMBY CREEK",
               @"LAKE THOM-A-LEX", @"LINWOOD", @"OPTIMIST", @"SOUTHMONT"];
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
   {
       [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
       // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }

   #pragma mark - Table view data source

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:  (NSInteger)section
    {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return _Parks.count;
    }


    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableCell";
        TableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        // Configure the cell...

        //int row = [indexPath row]; out of the blue I received warning 'implicit conversion loses integer precision:
        //'NSInteger' (aka 'long') to 'int' - solution on SO was to use NSInteger
        NSInteger row = [indexPath row];

    cell.ParksLabel.text = _Parks[row];
    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowDetails"]) {
        ListDetailViewController *detailviewcontroller = [segue destinationViewController];

        NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        //int row = [myindexPath row]; out of the blue I received warning 'implicit conversion loses integer precision:
        //'NSInteger' (aka 'long') to 'int' - solution on SO was to use NSInteger
        NSInteger row = [myIndexPath row];

        detailviewcontroller.DetailModal = @[_Parks[row]];
    }

}
@end
```

MapViewController.h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MapViewController : UIViewController {

    MKMapView *mapview;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapview;


-(IBAction)SetMap:(id)sender;

@end
```

MapViewController.m - I didn't include all of the code for the pins - just one to give you an idea

```
    @interface MapViewController ()

@end

@implementation MapViewController

@synthesize mapview;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //set initial extent
    MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0}, {0.0,0.0}};
    region.center.latitude = 35.8207;
    region.center.longitude = -80.2563;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.475f; //sets zoom extent
    region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.475f;
    [mapview setRegion:region animated:YES];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D bombayPin;
    bombayPin.latitude = 35.6300;
    bombayPin.longitude = -80.1030;
    MapPin *bombayanno = [[MapPin alloc] init]; //anno = annotation
    bombayanno.title = @"Bombay";
    bombayanno.coordinate = bombayPin;
    [mapview addAnnotation:bombayanno];

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//MapView Delegate Methods
//each time an annotation appears on map this method is called
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {

    //check to see if anno is not the ones we created but the default one that shows current location - don't want this one
    if([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;


    //create pin view
    MKPinAnnotationView *myPin = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"MapPinIdentifier"];

    myPin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
    myPin.animatesDrop = YES;
    myPin.canShowCallout = YES;

    //add detail disclosure button to display details in another view
    UIButton *detailButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    [detailButton addTarget:nil action:nil forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    myPin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = detailButton;

    return myPin;
}

// user tapped the disclosure button in the callout
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowDetails" sender:view];

}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowDetails"]) {


    }
}

-(IBAction)SetMap:(id)sender; {

    switch (((UISegmentedControl *) sender).selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:
            mapview.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
            break;
        case 1:
            mapview.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
            break;
        case 2:
            mapview.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Please do not dump huge amounts of code here. You should reduce the code to the parts you think are relevant.

Comment: I stated that i am new to this so I don't know what is relevant and what isn't. That is why I posted the amount that I did.

Answer (score -1):

Just create a separate segue to the same controller in storyboard.

You can also call your named segues in code with

```
[[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail"];
```

Comment: I've done that, but I don't know how to pass that info from map view to that controller as it is all done in the table view controller.

Comment: You do that in `prepareForSegue`: just check if the passed segue has the right name, get a reference to the destination via `segue.destinationController`, and set a `@property` of the destination controller that contains or references the data you want to display.

Answer (score -1):

It may be not the best Method but this could fit your needs, you could use `NSUserDefaults` to store a specific setting.

To save something to `NSUserDefaults`:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:yourObject forKey:@"mySavedKey"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

To retrieve something:

```
yourObject = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"mySavedKey"];
```

where yourObject may be a `NSString`, `NSArray` etc. you may look up the desired and suitable objects on the Apple Developer Page.

[Apple Developer Resources](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsuserdefaults_class/reference/reference.html)

`NSUserDefaults` is app-wide available, so you can access it from anywhere in your app, thats why it makes it fit for your need to "transport" data from one `ViewController` to another.